# Where to declare Angular catch all (Not found) route

Tags: angular, routes, angular5, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I have a main `app.routing.module.ts` as so:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

And then a couple of child routing modules:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'AbcRoute1', component: AbcRoute1Component },
    { path: 'AbcRoute2', component: AbcRoute2Component }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AbcRoutingModule {}

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'DefRoute1', component: DefRoute1Component },
    { path: 'DefRoute2', component: DefRoute2Component }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class DefRoutingModule {}
```

I am referring to this as the catch all route:

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

If I put it in the `AppRoutingModule`, then it kicks in if it doesn't match any routes defined in `AppRoutingModule`.  For example I am not able to go to `https://myapp/DefRoute1` which is defined in `DefRoutingModule`

If i put it in `AbcRoutingModule`, then all local routes work but stuff in `DefRoutingModule` doesn't work.

Where do I put this so that it will only match if all my routing modules fail to match the url?

Comment: OK after asking this i discovered it on https://angular.io/guide/router that you should put the Root routing module as the last of the imports and that fixes it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ensure the `AppRoutingModule` (the root routing module) is declared last in the Module imports.  Then declare the catch all wildcard in there.   Docs link: https://angular.io/guide/router#routing-module-order

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    //...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,    
    HttpClientModule,
    // all other modules including any child routing modules

    // Last module
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    //..
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    //..
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```